# Ruby on Rails controller redirect not happening with WEBGL running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine, iframe, unity-webgl

I have a WEBGL player embedded in a rails static page as 'demo_path' like below:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= link_to "mindpass", demo_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
%>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the button, it loads the webgl template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf- 
8">
<title>Unity WebGL Player | MindPass_DEMO</title>
<script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
<script>
  var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", 
"/assets/Build/MindPass_WEBGL_RY2.json");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gameContainer" style="width: 90%; height: 90%; position: 
absolute; margin: auto;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This loads successfully and actually initiates the users controller to save a new user and initiates the 'redirect_to @users' as shown in the following users_controller code:

```
def create
    puts "create runs"
    #puts params.inspect
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save

      puts "user save runs"
      log_in @user
      puts "second welcome to your vault(users_cont)"
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to your vault!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      puts "render new runs"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The problem is that the redirect doesn't actually happen. Here is the log from the attempt, including the redirect:

> 2018-11-07T05:04:21.897020+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:21.896891 #20]  INFO -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee] Started POST "/signup" for
>   76.120.71.73 at 2018-11-07 05:04:21 +0000 2018-11-07T05:04:21.898131+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:21.898049 #20]  INFO -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee] Processing by
>   UsersController#create as */* 2018-11-07T05:04:21.901161+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I, [2018-11-07T05:04:21.901036 #20]  INFO -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee]   Parameters:
>   {"EMAIL"=>"jakeywtf34@gmail.com", "PASSWORD"=>"[FILTERED]"}
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:21.902007+00:00 app[web.1]: W,
>   [2018-11-07T05:04:21.901922 #20]  WARN -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee] Can't verify CSRF token
>   authenticity. 2018-11-07T05:04:21.907902+00:00 app[web.1]: create runs
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:21.907965+00:00 app[web.1]: user_params runs
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:21.908031+00:00 app[web.1]: unless state in
>   user_params 2018-11-07T05:04:22.141541+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.141393 #20] DEBUG -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee]   [1m[35m (5.0ms)[0m 
>   [1m[35mBEGIN[0m 2018-11-07T05:04:22.145580+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>   [2018-11-07T05:04:22.145463 #20] DEBUG -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee]   [1m[36mUser Exists
>   (2.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE
>   LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2[0m  [["email",
>   "jakeywtf34@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.149368+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.149270 #20] DEBUG -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee]   [1m[35mSQL (2.1ms)[0m 
>   [1m[32mINSERT INTO "users" ("email", "created_at", "updated_at",
>   "password_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"[0m 
>   [["email", "jakeywtf34@gmail.com"], ["created_at", "2018-11-07
>   05:04:22.146010"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-07 05:04:22.146010"],
>   ["password_digest",
>   "$2a$10$g.RhGJDfl23/zPDeyXEI.OcnsfKfYH3jE4GB7py6/ktMJ3N6y73OW"]]
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.153387+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.153287 #20] DEBUG -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee]   [1m[35m (3.5ms)[0m 
>   [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m 2018-11-07T05:04:22.153528+00:00 app[web.1]: user
>   save runs 2018-11-07T05:04:22.153618+00:00 app[web.1]: second welcome
>   to your vault(users_cont) 2018-11-07T05:04:22.154318+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.154239 #20]  INFO -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee] Redirected to
>   https://immense-castle-53592.herokuapp.com/users/126
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.154585+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.154507 #20]  INFO -- :
>   [c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee] Completed 302 Found in 253ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms) 2018-11-07T05:04:22.221827+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.221705 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359] Started GET "/users/126" for
>   76.120.71.73 at 2018-11-07 05:04:22 +0000 2018-11-07T05:04:22.229274+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.229112 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359] Processing by
>   UsersController#show as */* 2018-11-07T05:04:22.230258+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.230174 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Parameters: {"id"=>"126"}
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.156370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
>   path="/signup" host=immense-castle-53592.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=c5de6e8e-58e2-4177-ae17-e1f58fbb65ee fwd="76.120.71.73"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=264ms status=302 bytes=559
>   protocol=https 2018-11-07T05:04:22.419460+00:00 app[web.1]: D,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.419270 #6] DEBUG -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   [1m[36mUser Load
>   (6.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
>   "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 126], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.469417+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.469246 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Rendering users/show.html.erb
>   within layouts/application 2018-11-07T05:04:22.470569+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.470487 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Rendered users/show.html.erb
>   within layouts/application (1.0ms) 2018-11-07T05:04:22.484847+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.484727 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Rendered
>   layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (4.8ms)
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.497488+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.497361 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Rendered
>   layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms) 2018-11-07T05:04:22.526778+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.526644 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Rendered
>   layouts/_header.html.erb (12.1ms) 2018-11-07T05:04:22.540219+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.540092 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359]   Rendered
>   layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms) 2018-11-07T05:04:22.541427+00:00
>   app[web.1]: I,
>
> [2018-11-07T05:04:22.541342 #6]  INFO -- :
>   [972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359] Completed 200 OK in 311ms
>   (Views: 83.8ms | ActiveRecord: 103.3ms)
>
> 2018-11-07T05:04:22.544712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/users/126" host=immense-castle-53592.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=972376e5-2f11-4985-91fe-53b071181359 fwd="76.120.71.73"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=324ms status=200 bytes=2692
>   protocol=https

When I do this with normal form inputs like below, the same redirect log happens, and it actually goes to the users page.:

```
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
```

It seems as if WEBGL is locking this thing up and refusing the page to actually redirect, even though it *should be happening*. What am I missing?

**UPDATE 12-6-18:**

I noticed that when redirect is initiated by WEBGL (unsuccessful) I get this in the log: Processing by UsersController#show as */*. If I redirect from a normal html form (successful) I get this in the log: Processing by UsersController#show as HTML. This is the only difference in the logs.

I have tested for the following:

1. Tested with multiple browsers to see if it was specific to certain ones
2. Tested with changing the redirect URL to https://www.google.co.uk/ to see if redirect was successful
3. Added a condition to ensure that the redirection was finished before moving on with the scripts
4. Attempted testing off of Heroku via LocalHost (still did not proceed)
   Sadly, none of these tests have yielded any telling results.

Applicable UnityWebRequest C# Code from the gameInstance:

```
phase4 = true;
        Invoke ("QuitGame", 10f);
  }
      }

    private  IEnumerator  Connection ( string  name )
    {
    WWWForm  form  =  new WWWForm ();
    form . AddField ( "EMAIL" ,  _email );
    form . AddField ( "PASSWORD" ,  passwordUnityEncrypted );
    form . AddField ( "HOST_URL" ,  absoluteURL );
    form . AddField ( "SIGNUP_PATH" ,  _url_signup_route );
    form . AddField ( "LOGIN_PATH" ,  _url_login_route );

    if (absoluteURL == _url_signup){
    UnityWebRequest  request  =  UnityWebRequest . Post ( 
    _url_signup_route ,  form );
    yield  return  request . Send ();
    } else{
    UnityWebRequest  request  =  UnityWebRequest . Post ( 
    _url_login_route ,  form );
    yield  return  request . Send ();
    }
```

Comment: Any advice that is even remotely helpful is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm making a couple of assumptions here, but I'm assuming that the javascript behind the `gameInstance` is submitting the post request, if that is the case then I'd check that it's handling the redirect correctly.

*Updated*

You will need to handle the redirect manually (if I understand Unity documentation correctly).

You can get the redirect URL from the location header using [UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeader](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeader.html)

Once you have the location URL you should be able to use [Application.OpenURL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html) which will update the browser location if you're using the web player.

```
private  IEnumerator  Connection ( string  name ) {
  WWWForm  form  =  new WWWForm ();
  form . AddField ( "EMAIL" ,  _email );
  form . AddField ( "PASSWORD" ,  passwordUnityEncrypted );
  form . AddField ( "HOST_URL" ,  absoluteURL );
  form . AddField ( "SIGNUP_PATH" ,  _url_signup_route );
  form . AddField ( "LOGIN_PATH" ,  _url_login_route );

  string post_url = "";
  if (absoluteURL == _url_signup) {
    post_url = _url_signup_route;
  } else { 
    post_url = _url_login_route;
  }

  UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(post_url, form);
  yield  return  request.Send();

  string location = request.GetResponseHeader('location');
  Application.OpenURL(location);
}
```

My C# is rusty/non-existent so there could be bugs in there, but that should give you a direction to follow.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I added the C# code from the unity model that forms the WEBGL in the gameInstance which makes the request. The redirect is initiated by the users controller as a result of the request. I'm at a loss with regards to how to check that the gameInstance would be handling the redirect correctly.

Comment: As is, Appication.OpenURL(location) opens 'https://mindpass.herokuapp.com/demo', which is the url which opens the original gameInstance. I'm not certain whether this is because 'location' is being passed as 'https://mindpass.herokuapp.com/demo', or if the GetResponseHeader is returning null, resulting in a null 'location' in Application.OpenURL(location) to open the current url.

Comment: I also tried setting a custom header "locationUser" from the users_controller and then using locationUser rather than location for the GetResponseHeader. Same result. I need to look into this a bit more.

Comment: I tried setting an arbitrary link as a response header for the reroute and then getting it with GetResponseHeader and opening via Application.OpenURL. It worked. Now I just need to retrieve and send the correct URL as the response header and it should work. Will update. It's unfortunate that I couldn't redirect without the manual route, but your confirmation that it was absolutely necessary has been very helpful.

Comment: Woohoo that is awesome! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to handle the redirect in Javascript with Unity. Basically something like `document.location = "http://example.com"` but taking that `example.com` from the request's response (would be much better if the response was JSON with the path to be redirected to embedded inside)

Comment: Are you suggesting to code the gameInstance so that it recognizes a rails initiated request at the time of signup, which contains the redirect address? If so, would it then initiate something like this based on a conditional? Application.OpenURL("https://immense-castle-53592.herokuapp.com/users/98")